# Swift Audio from Video: Default to speaker

Tags: ios, swift3, avfoundation, avplayer

I am trying to play a video on the iPhone and it would be ideal if the audio from the video came out on the iPhone loud speaker.

However, i get this error on my console:

> audioSession error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -50.)

Here is my code ::

```
    let player = AVPlayer(url: video_url)

    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do {
        try audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.speaker)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("audioSession error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    // get the lenght of the video
    self.video_duration = getMediaDuration(url: video_url) + 0.25

    // notification for when video is over.
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.playerDidFinish), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)

    // the video controller...
    let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
    controller.view.frame = self.view.frame
    controller.player = player
    controller.showsPlaybackControls = false
    controller.view.tag = 99
    self.video_ctrl = controller

    // add controller as subview
    self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
    controller.player?.play()
```

I googled the error, and haven't seen any results.
Any help is appreciated.

Later on in the same app, I play an audio file using the same lines above for **AVAudioSession** and that works just fine. After that, if I replay the video, the sound will come out on the speaker, like I want it. But why does it NOT happen the first time?

Comment: Have you set an audio session category & activated the session? If so, which category? If you set a category, you can set `.OptionDefaultToSpeaker` as the option which should also work. This Q&A say that your method is the more "transient" version, which fits with what you're hearing: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1754/_index.html

Answer (score 3):

Just use option `.defaultToSpeaker`:

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: .defaultToSpeaker)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("AVAudioSession error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: I applied this category, sound comes from earphones, but only one side is playing the sound other side doesnot work. Any clue ?